# Help to perform Students T test

Tags: t-test, calibration

Where I work we calibrate devices and obtain the following equation each time:

y = a*x + b

"a" is the slope and "b" is the offset of the calibration equation. 
Until recently we had around 2000 calibration performed and hence 2000 data for a and b.

This week we renewed our system and after that we have done 10 more calibrations.

So we have 10 new a and b.
We need to investigate about the new slopes and offsets and compare them with the previous ones.

I am asked to make a Students T test and see if the last 10 new slopes and offsets, respectively, differ from the previous 2000 historical values?
I don’t have too much time to study everything from scratch. I would be glad any for any help.

Comment: Do you perform all calibrations for the same set of $x$ values in every case?

Comment: y = a*x + b is obtained as such: a rotary device outputs frequency versus  an applied water flow. in this case applied water flow speed is y, and the frequency is x. both frequency and the flow speed are measured during the calibration at various points. by using these points calibration equation is obtained. appled water flow steps are each time lets say around 4 5 10 m/s but of course not exactly %100 same. is that enough info?

Comment: It's important to know whether the calibration procedures were essentially the same each time or not.  The reason is that the intercept and slope estimates are intercorrelated, so comparing a new set of them to the old set requires knowing or estimating those correlations.  The amount of correlation can vary depending on the range and number of $x$ values used in each calibration. As an approximation we might be able to ignore details of the 2000 calibrations, but exactly how those 10 more calibrations were done is an important issue.

Comment: how can I calculate it? I have two sets of data with 2000 and 10. please guide me. and plus what is the indication of this test at the end?

Comment: Are you saying you have all the *raw* data for all 2010 calibrations, or just the slope and intercept measurements?

Comment: I have all the data. but it would be easier if i can use only slope and intercepts. since thats what i was asked for.

Comment: how would you do it in MATLAB or Excel?

Comment: Excel is done using a XY plot of the data then Add Trendline (linear) and show equation [x]  with 1st column is x, 2nd column is y,  highlight data and make graph, choose XY ( any format dot/line)  then select line in graph and right mouse add trendline.  It can be done without graphing easily but harder to explain in words.